# hibernate - cascade delete in many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

I have a spring mvc application that uses hibernate for working with mysql database. I have `acl` and `acl_group` tables. These two tables have `Many to Many` relationship with join table. Here is the structure of entity classes:

**Acl:**

```
public class Acl implements Serializable{
   ...
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "aclCollection",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Collection<AclGroup> aclGroupCollection;

  //Setter and getter
}
```

**AclGroup**:

```
public class AclGroup implements Serializable{
   ...
    @JoinTable(name = "acl_group_acl", joinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "acl_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "acl_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Acl> aclCollection;
    //Setter and getter
}
```

Now, I need to delete an `AclGroup` object and I want to all related records in the `acl_group_acl` table also be deleted. But when I try to delete an `AclGroup` object via hibernate, nothing happen and I got `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` exception with `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` message. Could anyone help me to solving this problem?

**Update:**

As @JB Nizet said, I removed `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`.  Now, `acl_group` record and related "acl_group_acl" records delete. But I got the following exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told Hibernate that all operations on an AclGroup must be cascaded to its collection of ACLs. So Hibernate, when you delete an AclGroup, also deletes all its Acls. Since it's a many-to-many association, the Acls that are being deleted are referenced by other AclGroups, so that causes a constraint violation.

It makes no sense to remove all the Acls of a group when you delete the group, since other groups also contain, and must continue to contain, the acl.

Remove `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, and everything should work fine.

Comment: This other problem is completely different. Please ask another detailed question, showing the relevant Spring method and the complete stack trace.